# What is time complexity of following code having 2 for loops?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

```
int count = 0;
        for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
```

Outer loop runs logn times and inner loop runs logn times, answer should be O(logn * logn), instead it is O(n), I am not getting how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you notice steps for `i` will be N, N/2, N/4 ...

and hence count inner loop will execute for

`N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 +....` times

and the sum for that series is `O(N)`

read more about the series here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: what about the outer loop, should'nt that be considered?
Then it would be O((logn)*n) right?

Comment: in first iteration of outer loop inner loop runs `N` times.. in second iteration of outer loop inner loop runs `N/2` times and so on